# Cable Modem connect to Netgear N300 Wireless Router and adsl Modem

Tags: connection, cable, adsl-router

I have a Netgear N 300 Wireless Router that is also a DSL Modem...  I want to
Go to a Cable Internet Provider.  Can I plug the Cable Modem into the N 300 Router and continue to use it as a Wirless Router?

Comment: **You should ask your Cable Internet Provider this question.**  There should not be a reason, but it could per your terms with said company, not be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on your provider and would best be a question for them.  In most cases there is no problem doing this but the ISP may need to make changes to their modem.   That is the case with the ISP I use in Canada